# Tab auto-completion working in jupyter but not ipython

Tags: python, autocomplete, jupyter, ipython

I'm quite new to coding so apologies if it has been asked already somewhere but I didn't find answer anywhere.

I am going through [python data science handbook](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.01-help-and-documentation.html) and I am currently working my way through exploring modules with tab completion.

While I get tab-completion of functions/commands in jupyter notebook, they are not working in ipython. I have installed jedi & pyreadline but it doesn't help. I'm working on windows.

So, in jupyter notebook:

```
L=[1,2,3]
L.<tab>
```

Gives me a list of functions I could use (e.g. L.append   L.copy). But in Ipython, it just produces an indentation.

Does anyone have had similar issues in the past and knows how to solve it?

Comment: They could have differ config file settings.